# jQuery: is there a generic way to obtain a map of element attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was wondering if there was a way to obtain a hashmap of attributes with jQuery, something as follows:

HTML:

```
<img id="site-logo" src="logo.jgp" alt="The Logo" class="ui-logo">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Something along these lines
$('#site-logo').getAttr();
```

RESULT:

```
{
   id: 'site-logo',
   src: 'logo.jpg',
   alt: 'The Logo',
   class: 'ui-logo'
}
```

I'm not interested in any plugins, just wondering if the jQuery guys thought of this one, I've been searching on google and tried the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method without any parameters but it throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have one, but the DOM effectively does: [`attributes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-84CF096), which is a [`NamedNodeMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922). Trivial to take that and create a JS object:

```
var attrs = {};
$.each($("selector")[0].attributes, function(index, node) {
    attrs[node.nodeName] = node.nodeValue;
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/awelul) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/awelul/edit)

So if this is something you want regularly, you can make yourself a plug-in:

```
// Attributes map plugin
(function($) {
  /**
   * attrMap builds a map of the attributes of the first matched
   * element in the set.
   *
   * @returns the object, or undefined if there are no elements in
   *          the set
   */
  $.fn.attrMap = attrMap;
  function attrMap() {
    var attrs;
    if (this[0]) {
      attrs = {};
      $.each(this[0].attributes, function(index, node) {
          attrs[node.nodeName] = node.nodeValue;
      });
    }
    return attrs;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
var attrs = $("selector").attrMap();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/awelul/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/awelul/3/edit)

Comment: @StevendeSalas: Yes, but it provides named accessors (e.g., `getNamedItem`). So `map.getNamedItem("foo")` is akin to `obj.foo`, though not (of course) as nice. Trivial to make a plain JS object out of it, though.

Comment: I think we might be on to something here, surprised that jQuery doesnt implement this though..

Comment: @StevendeSalas: I've added the thing I called trivial. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is no jQuery native built-in solution to create a hashmap from node attributes.

You can easily create a little method which will do the job, like @TJCrowder mentioned, use `.attributes` value, like:

```
var hashMap = { };

Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.getElementById('site-logo').attributes, function( elem ) {
   hashMap[ elem.nodeName ] = elem.nodeValue;
});

console.dir( hashMap );
```

<sup>The above code requires an ES5 enabled browser or a Javascript ES5 shim</sup>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/javascript-answers-using-es5-features-warn-or-not

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm so regulary using those methods, I don't even think about other dev's don't use somekind of a shim. Thanks for the headsup, again.